# Pass Python3 variable to C Shell Script

Tags: python, shell, csh

I did hours on research regarding the following question but I wasn't able to find an answer at all. Though there seem to be many fellows having problems with that. I hope I will recieve some help from the community. ;)

I have a Cshell script where I need to call a Python3 script from. Also I am passing a variable.
.csh

```
#!/bin/csh -f

set variable = value
/../geos.py $variable
```

So far so fine. In my Python3 script I take this variable, do some calculations and now want to pass back the 'new_variable' to the VERY SAME C shell script in order to proceed my set of data.

.py

```
import os
...
new_variable = 'foobar'
os.environ['new_variable'] = new_variable
return new_variable
```

My actual goal is that my C Shell script:

```
#!/bin/csh -f

set variable = value
/../geos.py $variable  

echo $new_variable
```

doesn't return 'Undefined variable'. So obviously my code doesn't work. Sure, I might be able to temporarily save the python calculations into a file but this seems quite unconvincingly. Also, I understand that it is just not possible to manipulate an environmental variable of the shell through a child process, but still I only want to pass a normal variable. There should be one way, no?
If it is possible, I wasn't able to figure out any solution using subprocess.check_call. What am I missing?

E D I T:
Merci beaucoup.

I knew that there must have been an easy solution. Thanks a lot!
For CSHELL the following code worked:

```
set new_variable=`../geos.py $variable`
echo $new_variable
```

For BASH the following code worked:

```
new_variable=`../geos.py $variable`
echo $new_variable
```

In the python script itself you don't need to do anything but putting your desired variable into standard output, e.g. print(you_even_can_name_them_as_you_want). No os.environ oo whatever necessary. Made my day. SOLVED

Comment: How will the python script write an environment variable to it's parent shell?

Comment: Child processes cannot change their parent's environment.

Comment: Is there a reason you can't return the value you want from the Python script then just `set` `new_variable` to the returned value in the shell script?  No file (at least explicit file) is necessary.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

in bash I'd use:

`new_variable=$(../geos.py $variable)`

Have the python script produce the new value as standard out (i.e. `print(new_variable)` )

In csh I don't know, maybe you would have to use backquotes instead of $() ?

Comment: Great answer. Back ticks work too: `new_variable=\`../goes.py $variable\``.